# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Skype silent when desktop is connected?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/skype-silent-when-desktop-is-connected)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Yahoo with WP8 GDR2 CardDAV / CalDAV](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2221/yahoo-with-wp8-gdr2-carddav-caldav)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Access WP8 System Files](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2196/access-wp8-system-files)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Windows 8 wont recognize my Lumia 925](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/windows-8-wont-recognize-my-lumia-925)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Increase video volume](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/increase-video-volume)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Key Press shortcuts in WP8](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/key-press-shortcuts-in-wp8)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Temporary files are not removing automatically](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/temporary-files-are-not-removing-automatically)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Can I prevent Facebook on WP8 returning to the top of the newsfeed every time I hit "Back"?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/can-i-prevent-facebook-on-wp8-returning-to-the-top-of-the-newsfeed-every-time-i)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Can't open photos, use store on my htc 8s](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2185/cant-open-photos-use-store-on-my-htc-8s)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to Display time on lock screen?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-display-time-on-lock-screen)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)